# formatando exportacao de comando sql com sed

Tags: sql, sed

Fiz a exportação de uma tabela do meu banco de dados da seguinte forma:

```
"1";"Boi Preto";"2000-02-29";"2";"Sol Nascente";"2009-10-01";"3";"Parque Belo";"2007-03-15";"4";"Pedras Bonitas";"2017-12-12";"5";"Medeiros";"2011-06-22";
```

e precisava deixar da seguinte forma abaixo:

```
01; Boi Preto; 2000-02-29
02; Sol Nascente; 2009-10-01
03; Parque Belo; 2007-03-15
04; Pedra Bonita; 2001-08-25
05; Nossa Senhora; 2011-06-22
```

como eu faço isso com sed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com `awk`, imprima três por três;

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {for (i=1; i<NF; i+=3) print $i, $(i+1), $(i+2)}' arquivo
"1";"Boi Preto";"2000-02-29"
"2";"Sol Nascente";"2009-10-01"
"3";"Parque Belo";"2007-03-15"
"4";"Pedras Bonitas";"2017-12-12"
"5";"Medeiros";"2011-06-22"
```

Se quiser, você pode salvar o código em um arquivo:

```
$ cat mola.awk 
BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}
{for (i=1; i<NF; i+=3) print $i, $(i+1), $(i+2)}
```

E facer:

```
$ awk -f mola.awk arquivo
"1";"Boi Preto";"2000-02-29"
"2";"Sol Nascente";"2009-10-01"
"3";"Parque Belo";"2007-03-15"
"4";"Pedras Bonitas";"2017-12-12"
"5";"Medeiros";"2011-06-22"
```

Comment: criei um arquivo chamado fmt.awk pra facilitar fiz chmod +x fmt.awk e cat esportacao.txt | ./fmt.awk

Comment: @dark777 O `awk -f fmt.awk esportacao.txt` :)

Comment: fiz isso mas ele me retornou o seguinte erro abaixo: bash-4.4$ awk -f fmt.awk exportacao.txt
awk: fmt.awk:2: awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {for (i=1; i<NF; i+=3) print $i, $(i+1), $(i+2)}' | sed 's/"//g;s/$/;/g' 
awk: fmt.awk:2:     ^ invalid char ''' in expression
awk: fmt.awk:2: awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {for (i=1; i<NF; i+=3) print $i, $(i+1), $(i+2)}' | sed 's/"//g;s/$/;/g' 
awk: fmt.awk:2:     ^ syntax error  removi o sed ele da o mesmo erro pois o sed removeria as aspas.

Comment: @dark777 Coloquei o código em um arquivo. Olhe para a minha edição

Comment: Agora funfou mas nao teria como usar o mesmo para remover as aspas?

Comment: @dark777 `awk -f mola.awk arquivo | sed 's/"//g;s/$/;/g'` funfou para mim.

Comment: dei uma pesquisada e consegui fazer com que removesse as aspas: BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {gsub("\"",""); for (i=1; i<NF; i+=3) print $i, $(i+1), $(i+2)}